# setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to move my bar button items up, because i change UINavigationBar height.

I used:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:-20.0 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It works for my `UIBarButton`  created with custom image, but not work for other one contained text. I want to move up my UIBarButton with text, declared like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *bbiDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Готово" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
```

How to move that up?

Answer (score -1):

```
//creat a custom view

let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))

//creat a button

let nvButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -40, width: 40, height: 40))

//add button to custom view's subview

customView.addSubView(nvButton)

let nvRightItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nvRightItem
```